# Unable to execute Selenium Java in IE

Tags: java, selenium

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Go on to the webpage (not recommended)")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
```

The above works and is able to click on the anchor link. However when I try to send in some keys it is not working. I am not sure where it is going wrong.

```
        
        //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@id='username']")).sendKeys("kiraa");
        
//      WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.id("username"));
//      element.click();
//      element.sendKeys("kiraa");
        
        
//      WebElement username = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[name='username']"));
//      username.click();
//      username.sendKeys("kiraa");
        
//      driver.findElementByCssSelector("input[name='username']").sendKeys("kiraa");
        
//      driver.findElementByName("username").sendKeys("kiraaa!");
        
//      driver.findElementByXPath("//input[@id='password']").click();
//      driver.findElementByXPath("//input[@id='password']").sendKeys("kiraa");
        
        List<WebElement> findElement = (List<WebElement>) driver.findElement(By.name("username"));
        List<WebElement> elements = findElement;
        System.out.println(elements.size());
```

```
For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'
System info: host: 'GBMACVCSW8354', ip: '11.15.90.232', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_162'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.ie.InternetExplorerDriver
Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: internet explorer, browserVersion: 11, javascriptEnabled: true, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), se:ieOptions: {browserAttachTimeout: 0, elementScrollBehavior: 0, enablePersistentHover: true, ie.browserCommandLineSwitches: , ie.edgechromium: false, ie.edgepath: , ie.ensureCleanSession: false, ie.fileUploadDialogTimeout: 3000, ie.forceCreateProcessApi: false, ignoreProtectedModeSettings: false, ignoreZoomSetting: false, initialBrowserUrl: http://localhost:37556/, nativeEvents: true, requireWindowFocus: false}, setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
Session ID: ab379905-fe0a-40aa-a3cc-6f4484b74bb1
*** Element info: {Using=name, value=username}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:122)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:49)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:158)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:323)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByName(RemoteWebDriver.java:404)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByName.findElement(By.java:284)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:315)
    at com.TestChrome.main(TestChrome.java:63)
```

Anyone please help.. Am stuck and not able to progress anywhere.

Comment: If possible [Edit] your question with url to check?

Comment: It is Splunk URL.